# What are good tools for carving in cork?

Tags: tool-selection, carving

What are good tools to carve in corks?

[image]
Actually, I'm using a simple kitchen knife but I guess there are better choices.

My goal is to carve some chess pieces.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean cork corks, not the new rubber ones?

Comment: Are you looking to do designs similar to the corks shown? Because you could probably use a wood burning tool to achieve that look.

Comment: @bowlturner So I have mainly cork corks. Anyway I noticed that rubber corks are much easier to carve (they are somewhat softer and breaks less easily).

Comment: @CreationEdge Wood burning sounds interesting but I'm not sure what it is. Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: You can buy wood burning kits that have a little tool sort of like a soldering iron, except you use it to burn designs into wood. You can get different attachments to make certain designs easier. It generally blackens the burnt part.

Comment: @CreationEdge Nice, I was not aware of that. This might be very useful to emphasize differences between black and white pieces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would lean toward scalples/X-Acto knives.  They a are very sharp, and the blades lend themselves to carving small details well.  They are designed for detailed work unlike kitchen knives which are designed to cut things up.

[image]

As Camil pointed out in the comments, a [heftier blade](http://www.walmart.com/ip/19-Hobby-Knife-Blade-TE01-193/41739432) might be needed to start with the larger roughing cuts so it doesn't snap.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I think this blade is not strong enough; it is meant for paper. I would suggest a blade like [here](http://www.walmart.com/ip/19-Hobby-Knife-Blade-TE01-193/41739432) which should not break as easily.

Comment: @CamilStaps I think both would be good, the heavier blade to rough out the shape and the lighter blade for detail work.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the level of detail you are trying to achieve, linoleum cutting tools may work well for you. I would highly suggest practicing on some spare cork first however - I have used these tools for linoleum printing and it takes a while to get the hang of things and avoid cutting yourself.

[image]

Comment: I remember doing linoleum at school and indeed, it was not so easy. The point is that if it is already not trivial on a flat surface, it might be very hard on a round surface. Anyway, it seems to be a good direction to explore.